# How to fix the type error: need variable, found value

Tags: class, variables, typeerror

I am writing a card class, and trying to create a method to compare two card's size, rank and value. And i have a problem that the system told me they need the variable but found a value. Do any one has some idea?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PbUh.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare two objects in the function. For example you created

```
Card cardA = new Card(<whatever>,<whatever>,<whatever>);
Card cardB = new Card(<whatever>,<whatever>,<whatever>);
```

Then you need to compare the above two Card objects

```
public boolean matches(Card A, Card B){
    if (A.suit() == B.suit()){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please also be noted that your `matches` function will return only comparison for suit. Not sure if you expect return true or false after ALL comparison (i.e. rank, suit ...)